# why do I get, image can't be displayed because of error with my code?

Tags: c, server

I'm trying to load the image Koala.jpg (from the browser) that is specified by the user, but what ends up happing is a never ending load screen then an error with image can't be displayed. why is that?

```
void *connectionThread(void *socket_desc){

    FILE* fd;
    char buffer[256];
    int newsockfd = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int n;  
    magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_ERROR|MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
    magic_load(myt,NULL);

    bzero(buffer,256);

     while (1)
     {memset(buffer, 0, 255);n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");//error checking

     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);    

     if((strncmp(buffer,"GET",3) == 0)){ //GET request
        char *header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: ";

    //st_size filesize = stat(buffer, &st);

        char *token = strtok(buffer," ");
    if(token !=NULL)
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    token = strtok(token,"\n");
    token = strtok(token,"/");

    fd = fopen(token, "rb");

    send(newsockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
    printf("token is: %s\n",token);
    printf("magic output: '%s'\n",magic_file(myt,token));   
    //write(newsockfd,"<",strlen("<"));  
    write(newsockfd,magic_file(myt,token),strlen(magic_file(myt,token))); //get Content-type
    //write(newsockfd,">",strlen(">"));
    write(newsockfd,"\r\n",strlen("\r\n"));
    write(newsockfd,"Content-Length: ",strlen("Content-Length: "));
    write(newsockfd,"780831\r\n\r\n",strlen("780831\r\n\r\n"));



     }

     if ((strncmp(buffer,"quit",4) == 0)) //quit
    break;
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message\n May I have another\n",40);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     }
     write(newsockfd,"Ok, I am quitting\n",18);
     fclose(fd);
     close(newsockfd);
     magic_close(myt);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I make the socket and bind it, in case something is off about that.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno,c;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    puts("Created socket");

     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);


     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");


     listen(sockfd,5);

     c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    pthread_t thread_id;

    while((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, (socklen_t*)&c))){
        if (newsockfd < 0) 
                error("ERROR on accept");

        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, connectionThread, (void *)&newsockfd);

    }
    close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have no synchronization on `newsockfd`. You pass the address of `newsockfd` to the thread, but then the main thread changes its value. You must never allow an object to be accessed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. You break this rule with `newsockfd`.

Second:

```
 printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings. At this point, `buffer` contains arbitrary image data.

Third: Your code reads some bytes from the incoming TCP connection and then acts as if it had read a message. But you never read a message. You have no code to read a message. If your application is going to use messages, you need to write code to receive a message. Just calling `recv` on the socket won't read a message because the TCP protocol is not a message protocol.

You probably have more issues, but those are the most serious.

Also, from a performance standpoint, it's awful to keep writing such small bits of data to a connection. Instead, assemble larger chunks in a buffer and use fewer calls to `write`.

Comment: buffer is the URL line which is read and then parsed to get what image to show. how does it contain the image data? also your saying i should use mutex to sync. the newsockfd? shouldn't every thread have its own variable newsockfd?

Comment: Also what do you mean just calling recv on socket won't read I never use recv in my code?